# how to make nomedia file in Android Q

Tags: android, android-10.0

Android Q could not create file on public directory.

is there has any way to make nomedia file on public directory?

without below code

`android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`

or is there has any way to hide media file on gallery

thank you.

Comment: What is public directory?

Comment: @blackapps File.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory is deprecated. but downloadmanager can do that with some limit. it allowed some directory like DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS DIRECTORY_PICTURES

Answer (score 0):

i solved it using download manager easily.

just download empty file from web.

this is my sample code

```
val downloadManager = context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
val request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/.nomedia"))
        .setTitle(".nomedia")
        .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM, "/test/.nomedia") 
        .setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI or DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
        .setAllowedOverMetered(true) 
        .setAllowedOverRoaming(false)
downloadManager.enqueue(request)
```

Comment: Does the DownloadManager create those subdirectories `"/test/.nomedia"`?